"ResultSet is positioned before first row" Problem, unsure of how to solve it
I've highlighted the particular point of issue.
 public void getCars(int uID) throws SQLException
    {
        int size = 0;
    int userID = uID;
    ResultSet temp2;
    int numRows = 0;
    int result = 0;
    ResultSet temp1;
    
    temp1 = query("SELECT CarID FROM Car WHERE UserID = '" + userID + "';");
    
    temp2 = query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRows FROM Car WHERE UserID = '" + userID + "';");
    
    while(resultSet.next()){
    numRows = temp2.getInt("numRows");
    }
     

****Under here is the part of code that I need help with (rest is for context)**
    while(size < numRows)
    {
    cArr[size] = temp1.getInt("CarID");
    temp1.next();
    size++;
    }
    }**

If any explanations of what the code means are needed I can provide, but pretty much, I have created a query that returns multiple rows and now I'm struggling to retrieve a row and put that row's data into an array then move onto the next row and insert that row into the next position of the array.
This is my first post here so apologies if the info I've provided isn't 100% helpful.
I tried to make the cursor that has read the first row in the query's result, returning it and giving it to the first position in the array, to then move onto the next line in the query's result and then repeat the process until the array is properly filled.
That's also pretty much what I expected that block of code to do and although I expected errors, I've been really struggling to find solutions for this particular one and I suspect that I'm misunderstanding how to use the .next() method for the ResultSet class.

You're doing while(resultSet.next()) but where is the resultSet variable declared and initialized?

Make life a lot easier for yourself and fetch into List<Integer> No need to count anything then. Also, a. use PreparedStatement and b. use try-with-resources for your DB objects

Does this answer your question? Java SQL: Error before result set. Tip: paste your error message into your search engine along with one or two pertinent keywords.

Your problem is that you need to call ResultSet.next() before getting any data from a ResultSet. You're calling temp1.getInt() before your first call to temp1.next(), hence the exception.
You might get away with putting the line temp1.next() before the line cArr[size] = temp1.getInt("CarID");, but I wouldn't do that. You're relying on numRows being the correct number of rows contained in the ResultSet temp1. That may not be the case. Someone may have added/removed rows between executions of your two SQL queries. The correct way to loop would be:
    List<Integer> carIdList = new ArrayList<>();
    while(temp1.next()) {
        carIdList.add(temp1.getInt("CarID"));
    }
    int numRows = carIdList.size();


Thanks for the reply. I've made the changed, but I'm still getting the same error, which I'll  provide in full here:
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.x.x invalid cursor state: identifier cursor not positioned on row in UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or GET statement: ; ResultSet is positioned before first row

@MatthewSteele there shouldn't be an error at the temp1.getInt call if you've just done while (temp1.next()). Check the stack trace and specifically the line number where the error was thrown; perhaps it was for another ResultSet.

The issue is now solved, it was breaking at a different ResultSet, but I never knew you had to .next() before each one? I know now though, thanks!

Yes, ResultSet objects are independent from each other and they each hold a separate cursor to the data.

resultSet.next(); must be put before each use of the ResultSet object.
(^"resultSet" being the specific ResultSet object you're working with)
Thanks to k314159 for the help

If k314159's answer helped you, why don't you just accept it? I don't understand the need for this answer that you posted. Have you taken the [tour]? Have you visited the [help]?
